# Why C# PInvoke can't work with unmanaged DirectX

Tags: c#, c++, interop, directx, com-interop

I've been using C# for a year, I know that you can access native code from C# via interop/PInvoke.
I just started to learn DirectX and learned that one of the few ways to use DirectX with c# is by using something like SharpDX which is a wrapper written in c++ and not C#.
my question is; since C# support interoperability and allow the programmer to access native dlls/com objects. how-come this support isn't valid when it comes to DirectX dlls/coms. I'm very confused

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not correct. SharpDX is a pure C# wrapper that is using some C++/CLI techniques through IL bytecode post-processing on the .NET assemblies. See the original [post](http://xoofx.com/blog/2010/10/19/managed-netc-direct3d-11-api-generated/) for more details. (In the section "How to avoid the usage of C++/CLI in C#"). For implementing a C++ interface callbacks in C#, you can have also a look at this [post](http://xoofx.com/blog/2010/10/25/implementing-unmanaged-c-interface/).

Even without the `calli` IL bytecode instruction, it would be perfectly possible to develop a full wrapper of COM objects using unmanaged delegates (through `Marshal.GetFunctionPointerForDelegate`). You can also do it with regular [COM interop](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645736%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) in C#.

On the other hand, if the C++ objects doesn't provide a COM interface (i.e only pure virtual methods) you will need a simplified C++ wrapper access for it or deal with the export mangling names for C++ objects (which is, afaik, not standardized)

Comment: Thanks, this was very insightful. I guess learning C# without learning CLR/IL, Is Similar to someone learning ASP.Net and then assuming he/she knows how the web work. I'm just amazed of the amount of C# programmers out there (mainly in game dev forums) who claims there is no way to use DirectX with C# except through slimDX or SharpDX

Answer (score 2):

PInvoke is rather limited, and is applicable to C-style APIs, like Windows API.
There are very small set of types, that could be marshaled.
Similar limitations exist for COM interop.

DirectX APIs are mostly C++ ones. You can't pass C++ class between boundaries - it's a headache. But C++/CLI is a way to go - it helps you to built some sort of bridge between managed and native world.